# Lost land after winning a war?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

This puzzles me so much.

I am playing as Sweden. I built up enough power to be able to bully Denmark as I please. They still have most of their 1066 territories. Then I saw that I can "Claim Denmark". Awesome, so I can get all territories at once. I declare war, I proceed kicking them around until I get 100% warscore. Time to cash in. I enforce my demands. And PUFF: not only Denmark is still independent, but it got a freaking half of my territories!

Is such a thing even possible? Or is it a bug?

I don't remember if at a time I was also King of Norway or if I already lost it for succession, but I don't know if this should influence it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely what happened is that the "claim" on Denmark was not your personal claim, but that of one of your vassals. Since you cannot have a king as a vassal (I assume you are not an emperor), upon victory, your vassal gained the Kingdom of Denmark, became independent, and also took his existing land with him.

To avoid this in the future, pay attention to what and whom you're actually declaring war for! The tooltips on the declare war menu should clearly delineate what the potential outcomes of a war are.

Comment: Sad but true :(

Comment: Exactly this. Don't ever push a claim for somebody else if they will end up with an equal or higher rank than you (or for somebody who isn't already your vassal for that matter). Unless you just want them as a ally, which probably won't last long anyway.

Comment: This game is significantly different from other strategy/war games where you play a supreme ruler or even the general spirit/embodiment/zeitgeist of a people. The answer is very helpful at ramming this point home.